# scheme - equal function with lists

Tags: scheme

I wrote this program:

```
(define find-combination
  {lambda (a b)
    (if (eq? ((quotient (car a) (car b)) (quotient (car (cdr a)) (car (cdr b)))))
         (display "1*v1" + ((quotient (car a) (car b))*"v2"))
         (display "0*v1" + "0*v2"))})

(find-combination (list 2 2) (list 2 1))
```

a and b are two lists. Its give me the next problem: procedure application: expected procedure, given: 1; arguments were: 2.

I didn't get what is the problem. Someone can help me? Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have too much brackets after `eq?` - what you wrote means evaluating `(quotient (car a) (car b))` and treating it as a function with argument `(quotient (car (cdr a)) (car (cdr b)))`.  The error means that first thing was evaluated to `1` and your interpreter expected it to be a procedure, not an integer.  This line should be:

```
(if (eq? (quotient (car a) (car b)) (quotient (car (cdr a)) (car (cdr b))))
```

or even:

```
(if (eq? (quotient (car a) (car b)) (quotient (cadr a) (cadr b)))
```

Apart from that, lines with `display` calls are wrong - Scheme doesn't have an infix notation, so `+` and `*` are out of place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a set of curly braces in your code(the one before lambda)

Also you have another set of paranthesis around the parameters you passed to eq?
It should be something like this:

```
(eq? (quotient (car a) (car b)) (quotient (car (cdr a)) (car (cdr b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme and Racket, parentheses change the meaning of things.

```
1
```

is a number, but

```
(1)
```

is a *call* to 1 as a function... but 1 is a number, not a function, so this will cause the error you describe.

Your use of curly braces is also a little unsettling to me.